# How to add ID from PHP script to JavaScript code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script which Edit and Delete cars on my website. Now I want to make Edit and Delete buttons inside a dropdown, and I did but its adding dropdown just to the first car from the row, since the ID is the same for every dropdown. Now I know how to get the unique ID from every car from PHP but how can I achieve it in JavaScript. I will show you my code.

PHP:

```
$id = $row["id"];

<div class='dropdown'>

    <button onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtn'>Settings</button>

    <div id='myDropdown".$id."'class='dropdown-content'>
     ".($featured!=1 ? "<a title='Make ".$title." Featured'href='forms/addfeatured.php?id=".$id."'>Make Featured</a>" : "<a title='Remove ".$title."' href='forms/removefeatured.php?id=".$id."'>Remove Featured</a>")."

    <a title='Delete ".$title."' href='forms/deletecars.php?id=".$id."'>Delete</a>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I have different ID in javascript so I can open dropdowns for each entry?

Comment: Your PHP code looks quite suspicious! It should fail more or less at the beginning of your HTML code...

Comment: this is not the full code

Comment: It's not reproducible like this, so it's quite useless. Especially it's not clear in which kind of construct you use your HTML statements.

Comment: what are you talking?

Comment: I am talking about your code. It's one of StackOverflows major rules to provide reproducible code. Your code isn't.

Comment: It might be difficult to select an ID attribute in DOM, when it has another ID attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Only use , No need to technically learn AJAX or JSON !

You Just need to use the simple functions which has been prepared for use and has been put in the libraries.  And set a few parameters that they need.

The important thing is that, **You should know PHP runs on the server machine, not your browser or your PC**.
So the PHP variables too.. They are not in your machine to easily put them in a JS variable.

At his point we need to communicate with the server to send them(using AJAX function) in a proper format(using JSON function) for us to use.

So, Your question :

> How to add ID from PHP script to JavaScript code?

has the easiest solution just with these functions:

(At your browser page): 
$.ajax({ .. some parameters .. });

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({ 
       type: 'post',       //Transfer Protocol
       url: 'serving.php', //Address of Server Page
       dataType: 'json',   //Data Structure
       data: {action: 'demo'}, 
       success: function(output) {
              $variables = output;
              }
     });
  });
```

and

(At your PHP page on the server)
json_encode(.. some data ..);

```
$variables = array("Chevy", "BMW", "Ford");
echo json_encode($variables );  // Encoded variable array
```

Unfortunately your codes and description are not clear for me to help directly in your project.

But I attach a simple practical Example :(in Jquery)

```
// carSelection.html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
  /jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> //jquery CDN
</script> 
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin:2em">
    <form id="myForm">
      <select id="selectNumber">
        <option>Choose a car</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div> 

  <script>
    var $cars = '';
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({ 
        type: 'post',
        url: 'carServs.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'demo'},
        success: function(output) {
        $cars = output;

        var option = '';
        for (var i=0;i<$cars.length;i++){
        option += '<option value="'+ $cars[i] + 
        '">' + 
        $cars[i] + '</option>';
         }
        $('#selectNumber').append(option);           
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And

```
// carServs.php page
<?php
  // ...
  $cars = array("Chevy", "BMW", "Ford"); 
  echo json_encode($cars);
  //...
?>
```

- just remeber to attach the **jquery CDN** at your code, In the head section or just before ending the body tag `</body>`

And if you insist to have it in JavaScript, It's possible just with a few changes in syntax.